# Normed spaces: Sum of closures is a subset of the closure of the sum

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $E$ be normed space and $A,B\subset E$. Show that
$
\overline{A}+\overline{B}\subset \overline{A+B},
$
where $A+B=\{ a+b :a\in A \text{ and } b\in B \}$.

Now I know this is true if $A$ and $B$ are subspaces, but is this true in general i.e. when $A$ and $B$ are just subsets of $E$? I haven't found a counter example and I have no clue how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a=\lim a_n$ and $b=\lim b_n $, then you have to show that  $a+b=\lim (a_n+b_n) $.

Comment: Okay, that I can do. Am I right when I argument that since $a_n+b_n \in A+B$ for all $n$, it must follow from the closedness of $\overline{A+B}$ that $\lim(a_n+b_n)$ is an element of $\overline{A+B}$?

Comment: Yes. $\ \ \ \ $